# What is CCleaner for Android referring to by "Hidden Cache"?

Tags: cache

CCleaner for Android cleans regular cache and "hidden" cache.

What do they mean by "hidden" cache?

Answer (score 2):

Other apps mention that as well, e.g. the cleaners of Avast and AVG – so it seems this isn't specific to the app. I would guess they refer to the apps' "private cache" (i.e. a cache directory inside the apps' private space in `/data/data/<package_name>`).

[This developer article](https://medium.com/coding-blocks/goodbye-findviewbyid-say-hello-to-synthetic-binding-in-kotlin-d3727bd8438e) might give some insight. Quoting (emphasis mine):

> By default, Android Extensions adds a **hidden cache** function and a storage field to each container (Activity, Fragment, View or a LayoutContainer implementation) written in Kotlin. The method is pretty small so it does not increase the size of APK much.

Another insight [from our sister site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19618641/where-google-maps-keep-cached-map-files):

> … but other then that it's all saved on hidden cache partition.

Which suggests there's some special *hidden* cache partition somewhere – or the writer of that answer got it a bit wrong (which I think is the case).

A third variant: Some apps create "hidden cache folders" on the SD card. Now guess what "hidden" means here? `sdcard/Android/data/<some_app>/.cache` – a hidden directory (leading dot in the name) called `.cache`.

No straight answer, sorry – but my guess is it's referring either to the first or to the last of these 3 options. Highest likelyness is the latter – which seems to be confirmed by the [SD Maid wiki](https://github.com/d4rken/sdmaid-public/wiki/AppCleaner#generic)¹:

> "Hidden caches" targets cache like files that are in non-default cache directories, e.g. `videoCache`, `.cache`.

One thing for sure: they're NOT talking about [geo-caching](https://www.geocaching.com/play/hide) with that

---

¹ <sub>thanks to [SSS](/users/209819/sss) for this pointer!</sub>

Comment: From the [SD Maid wiki](https://github.com/d4rken/sdmaid-public/wiki/AppCleaner#generic), it seems to be variant 3. Ran it on my device, interestingly it also caught APKs from Aptoide under the `/sdcard/.aptoide/apks` folder. The folder's size is much bigger than the Aptoide size shown in Android app info, meaning that it is a special folder and clearing the cache, data, or uninstalling the Android app might not make the "Hidden Cache" go away (hence the use of the Cleaner).

Comment: Good pointer, @SSS – that was my strongest guess as well, just found no *literal* proof. Will integrate that with my answer.